# Value of Index Insert into next row using loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-apps-script

I want to Insert all the value of Array index , I'm using 2 dimensional array, but it only insert the last index in 2d array, I also use if to check if one of the index have a value if yes then the value will insert if not the index of will not going to be inserted.

```
 var arr = [[data1 , data2, data3], [data4 , data5, data6]];
 //data1 to data 4 have a value , data 5 and 6 is empty 
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for(var j =0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
          if(arr[i][j].length != 0 ){
           ToSheet.getRange(nextRow+1,2,1,3).setValues([arr[i]]);
           //It insert only the last index in array arr[1] even the index 0 have a value
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Your logic right now is that you go through `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` three times each and when the content of `arr[i][j]` is not 0 you write the whole `arr[i]` is that intended? If you want to insert the row regardless of value why are you making the check in the first place? Can you give an example of data supplied to the function and what you expect it to do with it?

Comment: yes if one  of the value in arr[i][j] is not equal to 0, i write the whole arr[i], even  one or two value of arr[i] is equal  to 0, but when the value of arr[i] is equal to zero this one will not going to be write. only the arr[i] that have a value

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var arr = [['data1' , 'data2', 'data3'], ['data4' , 'data5', 'data6']];
  var outerArray = [];

  //data1 to data 4 has a value , data 5 and 6 is empty 
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(var j =0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j].length != 0 ) {
        outerArray.push(arr[i]);

        ToSheet.getRange(nextRow+1,2,1,arr[i].length).setValues(outerArray);
        //It inserts only the last index in array arr[1] even if the index 0 has a value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I always define an outer array, and push the inner array into it, rather than trying to build the two D array literally.  Also, the number of columns that are getting written, might change, so use the length of the inner array to set the number of columns to write to.

Comment: Hi Sandy thanks for answering my problem , but when i try to run the code it's have an error that says "Incorrect range height, was 2 but should be 1" it only insert the first index but not the second index even if the 2nd index have a value.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your array `arr`.  I don't think it's in the format that you are telling us that it's in.  You need to use troubleshooting techniques, and step through the code line by line.  Open the following link and read it.  [Google Documentation - troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

Comment: 1 + for the link that helps me, i now use debugger thanks  @Sandy

Answer (score 1):

Problem solve by the help also of mr sandy, Thanks for helping i see that by using a method push and looping 3 times, for the value of index, i see that it's also add the value of arr[i], 3 times so to minimize the error of this i only use one loop the loop for the index and use or for the condition, and not i get what i want :),

```
function myFunction() {
   var arr = [[data1 , data2, data3], [data4 , data5, data6]];
   var outerArray = [];
 //data1 to data 4 have a value , data 5 and 6 is empty 
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if(arr[i][0].length != 0 || arr[i][1].length != 0 || arr[i][2].length != 0 ){
           outerArray.push(arr[i]);
           ToSheet.getRange(nextRow+1,2,outerArray.length,outerArray[0].length).setValues(outerArray);
           //(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
          }
      }
}
```